# How to prove that the sum of squares of distances from $M$ to four vertices of a rectangle is constant?

Tags: geometry, circles

We have a rectangle $ABCD$ and a point $M$ on its circumscribed circle.

How can we prove that the sum of squares of distances between $M$ and four vertices of $ABCD$ is constant?

Comment: Hint: the diagonals of the rectangle are diameters of the circumscribed circle, and each one forms a right triangle with point $M$.

Comment: @dxiv if $M$ was not located at one of four vertices of rectangle, is your hint correct?

Comment: Yes. An inscribed angle that subtends a diameter is a right angle. Therefore, $\triangle MAC$ and $\triangle MBD$ are right triangles for any point $M$ on the circumcircle of $ABCD$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\measuredangle DMB=\measuredangle AMC=90^{\circ}$.

Thus, by Pythagoras theorem we obtain:
$$AM^2+CM^2+DM^2+BM^2=AC^2+DB^2=constant$$ and we are done!